# Cloud Foundry Micro Bosh configuation

Tags: ssh, rsa, cloud-foundry

while configuring micro bosh with with the guide on:
http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/deploying-cf/ec2/

it says "Generate secure keys for the following placeholders:".
It then goes on to give a list.

It then specifically asks for an RSA key-pair for another set of values.

So what do they mean by "secure keys" in the first section (The one with many entries)?

Answer (score 0):

I am working through the same question. I did find the following link has a sample cf-aws-stub file to help move the ball forward:
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cfop/blob/master/share/spec/fixtures/cf-aws-stub.yml

It looks like any field which requires a user name, you create your own unique "name" for that field. All of the other fields requiring a password or secret, you can generate your own unique password for it.

For the 2 fields requiring RSA key pairs, it looks like you need to generate a private/public key set.
Here is another link on how to do this for the jwt fields:
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/docs/Sysadmin-Guide.rst#id9